# Keep keyboard of iOS SwiftUI TextField on the screen until user types correct input

Tags: ios, keyboard, swiftui, textfield

My iOS SwiftUI [TextField](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield) invites the user to type an Int.  After the user presses the return key, one of two things will happen.  If the input was an Int, we do some simple arithmetic and display the result in a [Text](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text).  Otherwise, we display the bad input in an error message in the Text.   In either case, the TextField's keyboard is dismissed.  How can I keep the keyboard on the screen if the user has typed bad input, and keep it on the screen until the user types acceptable input?   Thank you in advance, and thanks again to the people who answered my previous TextField questions.   macOS Catalina 10.15.6, Xcode 11.6.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var inputText: String = "";
    @State private var outputText: String = " ";
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter an integer:",
                text: Binding<String>(
                    get: {return self.inputText},
                    set: {
                        self.inputText = $0;   //$0 is the text in the TextField.
                        self.outputText = " ";
                    }
                ),
                onCommit: {
                    guard let i: Int = Int(self.inputText) else {
                        self.outputText = "Bad input \"\(self.inputText)\".";
                        return;
                    }
                    self.outputText = "The product is \(2 * i).";
                }
            )
                .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

            Text(outputText)
        }
        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)
    }
}
```